# Kera's val_acc 99.9% but predictions poor for multi label classification

Tags: tensorflow, keras

Updated to include more information and context.

I've spotted other questions similar to this before, but the solutions don't seem to help me. I've got ~1000 labels of font letters and I'm using sigmoid activation to return the probabilities of each label that it is a particular font. The fonts are grayscale and each class has about 60 images in it of varying size on a white background.

I'm using callbacks to prevent overfitting and it's running for 3 epochs and quickly getting to 99.99% val_acc and acc, with 3 epochs, the results look like this in the first epoch (500 steps):

```
24576/44371 [===============>..............] - ETA: 4480s - loss: 0.0185 - acc: 0.9982]
```

And at the end after 3 epochs:

```
44370/44370 [==============================] - 9634s - loss: 0.0177 - acc: 0.9989 - val_loss: 0.0177 - val_acc: 0.9989
```

The model predictions of the generated model are no where close, the closest being a 10% match of a font letter that looks completely different.
Something isn't right, could someone help me out here? Here's the model code:

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=(150,150,1), activation='relu'))
BatchNormalization(axis=1)
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(1000, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', #categorical_crossentropy
optimizer='adam',
metrics=['accuracy'])
```

My configuration options are:

- 500 training steps (also tried 2000)
- 0.0005 learning rate (also tried 0.1)
- batch size 32
- epochs between 5 and 20 I've tried but exiting early at 2 to stop overfitting (patience 2)

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Please make the question clearer, what is the task, how do the predictions looks like, and why do you think they are wrong?

Comment: thanks, I've updated the question with more details.

Comment: You didn't add the details I asked for, more importantly, what is the task? Is it multi-class classification?

Comment: Apologies, it's multi label classification. I would expect the top 10 predictions to return the correct font when and image of the font is passed in.

Comment: so you have 60000 images? And only 60 per class?

Comment: Does any image have more than one class label? The problem with multi-label is that you can't take the top-k and expect to make sense.

Comment: You wrote" of varying size". So all images have the same pixels, but the fonts are of different size within each pixel array, right?

Comment: I was hoping to take the top 10 with the highest percentage. Ie the top 10 fonts that look most similar.

Comment: And apologies by size, I mean font size rather than image size. The images are 150px x 150px with fonts size 1 to 60

Answer (score 1):

> ~1000 labels of font letters [...] each class has about 60 images in it of

so you only have 60 images per class?

Some points come to mind: If you use a [`ImageDataGenerator`](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/), you can increase the amount of input by rotation, shearing, zooming, etc. This increases the input range for the network. And you can set aside a `validation_split` to keep from training, to only be used in validation.

Comment: 60000 images with 60 per class is correct. The input to the prediction I'm expecting to have the fonts in normal format, so I don't expect them rotated, only a different size. That's what's causing me the problem perhaps, so many images with varying size, rotation isn't relevant.

Comment: I'm allocating 0.1 of the images from the input data for testing the prediction accuracy. Which all seem to resort to 99.9%

Comment: @ColinBrown: 60 per class is very few for 1000 classes/labels. Try adding zooming and shearing to increase examples per class. Re the second reply: did you use the `validation_split` parameter?